# $\lim_{j\to +\infty}\lim_{k\to +\infty}\cos^{2k}(j!\pi x)=\begin{cases} 1, & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\ 0, & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to prove the following statement but I have got stuck at one point, so I would be grateful if someone would give me an **hint** about how to go ahead, thanks:

$$\lim_{j\to +\infty}\lim_{k\to +\infty}\cos^{2k}(j!\pi x)=\begin{cases} 
1, & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0, & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

My proof:

It is known that $\lim_{k\to +\infty}y^{2k}=\begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if } -1<y<1,\\
1, & \text{if } y=\pm 1,\\
+\infty & \text{if } y>1,
\end{cases}$ and since $-1\leq\cos(z)\leq 1$ for every $z\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $$\lim_{k\to +\infty}\cos^{2k}(j!\pi x)=\begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if }j!\pi x\neq 2k\pi, \pi+2k\pi\\
1, & \text{if }j!\pi x=2k\pi, \pi +2k\pi
\end{cases}=\begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if }x\neq \frac{2k}{j!}\text{ and }x\neq \frac{2k+1}{j!}  \in\mathbb{Z}, j\in\mathbb{N}\\
1, & \text{if }x=\frac{2k}{j!}\text{ or }\frac{2k+1}{j!}, k\in\mathbb{Z}, j\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$$ so if $x$ is a rational number of the form $\frac{2k}{j!}$ or $\frac{2k+1}{j!}$ then the limit for $k\to +\infty$ is equal to $1$ (and so also the limit for $j\to +\infty$) and if it is not then the limit is equal to $0$.

**(ADDENDUM after Kavi Rama Murthy comment)**

Now, since any rational number is of the form $\frac{p}{q},\ p\in\mathbb{Z}, q\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ and it can be rewritten as $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{p\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot\dots\cdot (q-1)}{q!}=\frac{p\cdot (q-1)!}{q!}$ where the numerator is either an even or an odd integer we have that $x\in\mathbb{Q}\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{2k}{j!}$ or $x=\frac{2k+1}{j!},\ k\in\mathbb{Z},\ j\in\mathbb{N}$ so we can write $$\lim_{k\to +\infty}\cos^{2k}(j!\pi x)=\begin{cases} 
0, & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
1, & x\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$ thus $$\lim_{j\to +\infty}\lim_{k\to +\infty}\cos^{2k}(j!\pi x)=\begin{cases} 
0, & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
1, & x\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}. \square$$

---

If what I have done is correct then it seems to me that to finish the proof the only thing I need to do is to show that *every* rational number can be written in the form $\frac{2k}{j!}\text{ or }\frac{2k+1}{j!},\ (k\in\mathbb{Z}, j\in\mathbb{N})$ because then $x=\frac{2k}{j!}\text{ or }x=\frac{2k+1}{j!},\ (k\in\mathbb{Z}, j\in\mathbb{N})\Leftrightarrow x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x\neq\frac{2k}{j!}\text{ and }x\neq\frac{2k+1}{j!},\ (k\in\mathbb{Z}, j\in\mathbb{N})\Leftrightarrow x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and this is where I am stuck, so I would appreciate an **hint** about how to do this, thanks.

Comment: $\frac p q=\frac {(p)(1)(2)...(q-1)} {q!}$ and the numerator is either even or odd.

Comment: Alternative: if **fixed** $x = \frac{p}{q}$ and $j$ is any integer $\geq q$, then $([j!]x)$ is an integer, so $([j!]x\pi)$ is a multiple of $(\pi).$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you! If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\frac  p q$ can be written as $\frac {(p)(1)(2)....(q-1)} {q!}$  and the numerator can be written as $2k$ if it is even and $2k-1$ if it is odd.